convert date in rows to columns in Oracle19
I have from date and to date as parameter. I am getting result in rows as below query.
SELECT
  (to_date('29-04-2024','DD-MM-YYYY') - level + 1) AS day
FROM
  dual
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= (to_date('01-05-2024','DD-MM-YYYY') - to_date('01-04-2024','DD-MM-YYYY')+1 );


I want to change these rows to column in oracle. I want to do pivot in Oracle. I am new to Oracle database.
My desired output

Thank you

I converts to one single column, how can I convert to different columns select Listagg(a.day,' ')as d from(
SELECT
(to_date('29-04-2024','DD-MM-YYYY') - level + 1) AS day
FROM
dual
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= (to_date('01-05-2024','DD-MM-YYYY') - to_date('01-04-2024','DD-MM-YYYY')+1 )) a;

Oracle does not support dynamic pivots in SQL (you would need to use PL/SQL to construct a dynamic SQL statement or use XML or something similar). If you want to get a column-based output in SQL then hard-code the columns:
SELECT DATE '2024-04-29' AS DT_20240429,
       DATE '2024-04-28' AS DT_20240428,
       DATE '2024-04-27' AS DT_20240427,
       -- Etc.
       DATE '2024-04-03' AS DT_20240403,
       DATE '2024-04-02' AS DT_20240402,
       DATE '2024-04-01' AS DT_20240401
FROM   DUAL

Or, if you want to pass in the first day of the month and generate 31 columns for days (putting NULL values if you go outside the month boundary):
SELECT :start_month +  0 AS DAY1,
       :start_month +  1 AS DAY2,
       :start_month +  2 AS DAY3,
       -- Etc.
       :start_month + 27 AS DAY28,
       CASE WHEN TRUNC(:start_month + 28, 'MM') = :start_month THEN :start_month + 28 END
         AS DAY29,
       CASE WHEN TRUNC(:start_month + 29, 'MM') = :start_month THEN :start_month + 29 END
         AS DAY30,
       CASE WHEN TRUNC(:start_month + 30, 'MM') = :start_month THEN :start_month + 30 END
         AS DAY31
FROM   DUAL

However, what you probably want is to generate the dates as rows (not columns) and then pivot in whatever third-party application (Java, C#, PHP, Python, etc.) that you are using to talk to the database.
